# How to add different <text> to firestore?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, react-props

I am trying to send some text to the firestore doc and it sends no issues.

Please refer to part of a code of the picture: https://ibb.co/dL0V0yv

However i have a couple of buttons and i want to set my code in a such way so that every onPress will send different text. I could achieve that by re-writing the generateDoc fucntion with diffenet state manually, but i wonder how could i do it with copiying? Do something with props of function so that the text could be change inside onPress, but i do not knwo how to produce that. Please help.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up.

Comment: Sorry for that, i wont do that anymore. I was just struggling to use that formatting code, dont know why. I will do it right next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the function a parameter, like this...

```
generateDoc = taskName => {
  return firestore().collection('Rooms')... // OP code here
    .set({ Task: taskName }).then...
}
```

and call it like this...

```
onPress={this.generateDoc('task name for this button')}
```

**Edit**

To call two or more functions onPress, it's probably better to keep the template code clean and combine two promise returning functions into one, like this...

```
operationA = param => {
  return firestore()...   // be sure to return the promise
}

operationB = param => {
  return firestore()...   // same thing here, return the promise
}

operationAandB = (paramA, paramB) => {
  // if the A and B are independent, then do them together
  return Promise.all([ operationA(paramA), operationB(paramB) ])

  // or if A and B must run in sequence, then
  return operationA(paramA).then(() => operationB(paramB))
}

onPress={this.operationAandB('paramA', 'paramB')}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this info sir. I will try to do that . I got one more question. How could i add two functions to a single onPress? Just state them in a row? Like onPress = {   this.generateDoc,    this.someFunction } ??

Comment: Thanks a lot for tour reply, it is really easy to read and understand, much appreciated sir. But what is one of my functions does not have a parameter, and the other one does, could i combine them in the same way?

Comment: @9titashka Hey it's okay to ask follow up questions but if the answer solves the stated issue you should accept it. Doing so will make the question gain more relevance and other people with the same problem will easily find the solution.

Comment: @Ajordat, sorry o just forgot about that. Thanks for reminding. Appreciate help that i get on this website, a lot.